# C# Serialize JSON object within JSON objects

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have these entities:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public ICollection<Pack> Packs {get;set;}
}

public class Pack
{
    public string Colour {get;set;}
    public string Moq {get;set;}
}
```

my json object:

```
var products = [{
    code: 1243123,
    name: "Gel",
    packs: [{
        color: "blue",
        moq: 10
    }]
}];
```

note the naming differences, i.e. case and american spelling of color. Will the `JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject()` deserialise that correctly?

Or will I have to do it another way?

If I can just have an object where I can access those names directly and there values that would be great!

Comment: in your json `packs` is an array but in your `Product` class it's a single item, I think this will be an issue

Answer (score 2):

If you use something like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), then you can use attributes to control serialization, such as:

```
public class Pack
{
    [JsonProperty("color")]
    public string Colour {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("moq")]
    public string Moq {get;set;}
}
```

Also, given your expected output, your `Product` class should look like this I think:

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public long Code {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("packs")]
    public Pack[] Packs {get;set;}
}
```

Note *Code* and *Packs* type.

Comment: that seems really good, just means I cant change my model too much ;)

Comment: question: what if I literally just want the ids and one other field pulled out of that json object? the json object is used to make a table so I need all that information, however I cant be bother to write a parse to turn that data into a more simplified form, should I be bothered, will that make it easier, or can you just get the serialiser just to look at certain things?

Comment: No worries, I have implement a javascript function pulling out only the information i need, then I created c# objects that match identically, then got Newton `JsonConvert.DeserialiseObject<>()` to convert it, works a treat :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `DataContractJsonSerializer` instead, you can put attributes to your properties, giving them different names in generated/parsed JSON:

```
[DataContract]
public class Pack
{
    [DataMember(Name = "color")]
    public string Colour {get;set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "moq")]
    public string Moq {get;set;}
}
```